# Hide checkout billing fields based on user role

Tags: php, woocommerce

Question: how to add code that will only hide the billing fields based on the users role, in this case customer.

Using the following code we can hide billing details in cart from logged in users:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        exec($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WordPress [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) conditional function that works with user roles, like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( current_user_can('customer') ){
        exec($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this still shows the `billing_first_name_field` in my case. And also the Header. The following code works fine:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( current_user_can('customer') ){
        exec($fields['billing']);
        unset($fields['billing']); //this was changed
    }
    return $fields;
}
```